# как вызывать функцию addToCount() чтоб в console был 2 а не 1

Tags: javascript

```
var Counter = {
   count: 0,
   add: function(){
    this.count++;
    console.log(this)

   }
}

Counter.add();
console.log(Counter.count);
var addToCount = Counter.add
addToCount();
console.log(Counter.count);
```

Comment: `addToCount.call(Counter);`

Comment: Или же: `var addToCount = Counter.add.bind(Counter); 
addToCount();`